# F#: avoid race condition when calling Task.WhenAny?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

So after working quite a bit with F#'s `Async` model I think I wrapped my head around it and its differences with C#'s `Task` model. One of the things I really like about the way they interoperate is `Async.AwaitTask`:

```
...
public Task<int> SomeCsharpApiAsync() {
    ...
}
...
let someFsharpAsyncCode = async {
    let! someResult = Async.AwaitTask (SomeClass.SomeCsharpApiAsync())
    return someResult
}
```

With the code above, the line that calls AwaitTask not only awaits for the task to be completed, but also assigns its result to the variable `someResult` in an operation which I believe is atomic. Very neat!

However, I'm having a problem to achieve the same thing (atomicity, so lack of race conditions) when using `Task.WhenAny`:

```
...
public Task<int> SomeCsharpApiAsync(string someParam) {
    ...
}
...
let someFsharpAsyncCode = async {
    let task1 = SomeClass.SomeCsharpApiAsync "foo"
    let task2 = SomeClass.SomeCsharpApiAsync "bar"
    let! fastestTask = Async.AwaitTask (Task.WhenAny([task1;task2]))
    return fastestTask.Result
}
```

The problem about the code above is that the `AwaitTask` operation returns a task (the fastest), not the result, so it's an extra layer of indirection, which I resolve by calling `.Result` later. But I've found problems about this, whose culprit I think are race conditions: the fastest task may have some result at that moment, but when retrieving the result of it, the task's cancellationToken might have been requested (cancelled)! Or the fastest task was faster because actually was the one canceled faster? I'm not sure and I'm a bit lost on how to figure out what's happening here.

Maybe I can avoid the problem altogether by using an F# alternative to C#'s `Task.WhenAny`?

Answer (score 0):

See if this implementation of Async.WhenAny might fix your problem:
https://github.com/tpetricek/TryJoinads/blob/master/src/FSharp.Joinads/Async.fs#L9

See also this blog: http://tomasp.net/blog/joinads-async-implement.aspx/

This example is very similar to your code, but maybe there is a subtle difference: https://github.com/microsoft/fsharplu/blob/master/FSharpLu/Async.fs#L59

And here is another brief example with a different purpose, but still might be helpful:
http://www.fssnip.net/hx/title/AsyncAwaitTask-with-timeouts

Comment: thanks I'll take a look next week and give feedback!